# HAProxy http mode with ssl and simple acl behave weirdly

Tags: http, ssl, reverse-proxy, acl, haproxy

I am trying to configure HAProxy to only allow access on a server for URLs with a specific path begining. My config is as shown here:

```
frontend test
 mode http
 bind *:50005 ssl crt /crt.crt
 timeout client  10800s
 timeout server  10800s

 http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
 http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
 redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

 acl only_api path_beg,url_dec -m beg -i /api/v1
 http-request deny if !only_api
 use_backend out-pt.groupinfra.com if only_api

backend myserver
 mode http
 server out myserver.com:443
```

So basically 'myserver' uses https, so I need to forward it as https.
I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error from this.

I did have success using the tcp mode as the ssl simply passes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use ssl to connect to your backend server:

```
server out myserver.com:443 ssl verify none
```

or you need to verify certs

```
server out myserver.com:443 ssl verify required ca-file /path/to/your/backend/server.pem
```